# Which is more efficient? str[::-1] or ''.join(reversed(str)) in python?

Tags: python, string, join, slice, reverse

There isn't much to describe. Which would be faster between those two choices?

Comment: ...test it out?

Comment: There is only one way to find out... `timeit`

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Also, even though this is an example, be careful using `str` as a variable name.

Comment: Yes, I guess [::-1] would be much faster. timeit.timeit("s = 'abcdef'*50; x = s[::-1]") takes about .55 seconds while timeit.timeit("s = 'abcdef'*50; x = ''.join(reversed(s))") takes about 6 seconds